# How can I achieve prioritized x,y movement for a 2D top-down player in Unity using C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development

I am trying to create 2d top down player movement like in Pokemon.

- only x,y movement, no diagonals
- tiles based movement
- **prioritizes the most recent key pressed**

tile based movement isn't hard, there are lost of tutorials on that subject, but im having trouble combing x,y movement based on the most recent key pressed.

for example...
while holding "W" the player will move up, if they held the "A" in addition they would go left, once they let go of "A", player resumes going up.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float walkSpeed = 5f;
    public float runSpeed = 10f;
    public float currentSpeed;

    public Transform movePoint;
    public LayerMask Barrier;

    public bool isRun;

    void Start()
    {
        movePoint.parent = null;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)){
            currentSpeed = runSpeed;
            isRun = true;
        }
        else
        {
            currentSpeed = walkSpeed;
            isRun = false;
        }


        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, movePoint.position, currentSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, movePoint.position) <= .05f)
        {
            if (Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")) == 1f)
            {
                if (!Physics2D.OverlapCircle(movePoint.position + new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0f, 0f), .2f, Barrier))
                {
                    movePoint.position += new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0f, 0f);

                }
            }
        }
        else if (Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")) == 1f)
        {
            if (!Physics2D.OverlapCircle(movePoint.position + new Vector3(0f, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"), 0f), .2f, Barrier))
            {
                movePoint.position += new Vector3(0f, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"), 0f);

            }
        }


    }
}
```

This is the base that I have been editing trying to get it to work the way I want.
the prioritization of movement only works on one axis.

Not sure if the code I've provided is optimal or not, any better ways to approach the problem are welcome.

Comment: A common way to handle input and animations in games is with a state machine. I.e. have a ordered list of transitions, each checking if a key is pressed. If it is, transition into the corresponding animation state that moves the character.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to override the vertical input with the horizontal input by seting the other to zero when horizontal input is detected.

Here's a stripped down sample code, you can slap it onto a 2D sprite gameObject  parent to see how it feel:

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] private float currentSpeed = 10f;

    [SerializeField] private KeyCode _moveUp = KeyCode.W;
    [SerializeField] private KeyCode _moveDown = KeyCode.S;
    [SerializeField] private KeyCode _moveLeft = KeyCode.A;
    [SerializeField] private KeyCode _moveRight = KeyCode.D; 

    void Update()
    {
        // reset to zero every frame
        Vector3Int  moveDirection = Vector3Int.zero;
        
        // Get the Inputs
        if (Input.GetKey(_moveUp)) moveDirection.y = 1;
        if (Input.GetKey(_moveDown)) moveDirection.y = -1;
        if (Input.GetKey(_moveLeft)) moveDirection.x = -1;
        if (Input.GetKey(_moveRight)) moveDirection.x = 1;

        // Return when no input detected
        if (moveDirection == Vector3Int.zero) return; 

        // Use Horizontal movement to overrides vertical movements.
        if (moveDirection.x != 0) moveDirection.y = 0;

        // Move the transform using moveDirection
        transform.position += (Vector3)moveDirection * Time.deltaTime * currentSpeed; 
    }
}
```